# how to create or destroy session on login in cloudant

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, cloudant

I am trying to create cloudant session for my node JS application, I

```
var session = require('express-session');
var CloudantStore = require('connect-cloudant')(session);
var cloudantStore = new CloudantStore({
     url: cloudant database url [ https://@UserName:@Password@UserName.cloudant.com ] //required
     databaseName: 'sessions' (default sessions)  //optional
     ttl: 86400,                 //optional
     prefix: 'sess',             //optional
     operationTimeout:2000,      //optional
     connectionTimeout:2000,      //optional
});



cloudantStore.on('connect', function() {
    debug("Cloudant Session store is ready for use");
});

cloudantStore.on('disconnect', function() {
    debug("An error occurred connecting to Cloudant Session Storage");
});

var app = express();
app.use(session({
    store: cloudantStore,
    secret: 'your secret',
    cookie: {maxAge:24*60*60*1000} //stay open for 1 day of inactivity
}));
```

have seen these things wherever I go, but no documents clearly explain how do I create a session on user login and destroy it after the user logs out. Can someone please share a syntax of code snippet which is followed by snippet I have posted above. I want to create a session when the user is valid and redirect him to the home page

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation for [`express-session`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session). I believe that `connect-cloudant` is simply allowing you to use Cloudant as the session store for `express-session`. I think what you want is [`Session.regenerate`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#sessionregeneratecallback) for login and [`Session.destroy`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#sessiondestroycallback) for logout.